# Como o evento "hover" se comporta em dispositivos "touch"?

Tags: css, eventos

Estou desenvolvendo um site para se adequar aos dispositivos através de Media Queries, no entanto me pergunto, como certos eventos se comportam em dispositivos touch. Por exemplo, como o evento "hover" se comporta em dispositivos touch? E como substituí-lo ou adaptá-lo para dispositivos touch ?

Existe outros eventos semelhantes que devo rever com atenção?

Comment: Pelo que eu percebi em meus sites o :hover se comporta como o :active em dispositivos touchs.

Comment: Pelo pouco que descobri até agora, tem browser que ele ativa o hover só enquanto o touch tá ativado mas se tirar o dedo ele desliga...Pode imaginar a briga, o cliente quero comprar quero gastar, mas não consigo acessar esse link... hehe...Mas vlw o interesse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O hover, em dispositivo touch, funciona como clique.
Na ferramenta de desenvolvedor do chrome (F12) você consegue visualizar o funcionamento.

---

Pra melhor adaptar pra dispositivo touch você pode usar o [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs/#features-misc) e carregar a folha de estilo de acordo com a experiência:

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
   // Ação se for dispositivo touch
} else {
   // Ação sem dispositivo touch
}
```

Ou pra uma solução mais imediata você pode usar media query

```
@media screen and (max-width 768px)
   /* CSS em dispositivos mobile */
```

A resolução 768px é padrão de dispositivo mobile. O grande detalhe é que personalizando com CSS, se o usuário redimensionar o browser ele vai navegar com o mouse uma navegação otimizada para touch.

Comment: Então o problema é que li que em determinados dispositivos, se o cara tira o dedo ele some... como um hover mesmo, mas eu queria ver como posso fazer para o elemento ser hover e click...Num sei se entendeu...qq comenta e te explico melhor..

Comment: Você pode usar media query pra manter o estilo de click quando for em dispositivo menor de 768px (padrão de mobile)

Comment: Acho que vou preferir a solução com media query...vlw